# Reference about the surgery of Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I roughly read the Topping's *LECTURES ON THE RICCI FLOW*. There does not seem to be an introduction on surgery. Seemly, it is enough to deal singularity by blow up. Then, in order to know surgery, I read the Perelman's *Ricci flow with surgery on three-manifold*. But it is not easy to read.  Are there any books that introduce the surgery, and likely to Topping's book (I feel Topping's book is friendly to read) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group of five mathematicians (Bessières, Besson, Boileau, Maillot and Porti) have written [a book](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=122) aiming to give a complete proof of the Geometrisation Conjecture from pre-Perelman's results.

As such, they present a version of Ricci flow with surgery. I hope the book will appear suitable to you (I haven't read it in detail, but the introduction and first chapters seem remarkably clear to me).